# Output data of Erlang List as a HTML in Yaws

Tags: erlang, yaws

Have a look at my index.yaws file below

```
<html>
<body>
    <h4>Data:</h4>

    <erl>
        out(Arg) -> 
            Data = utilities:get_raw_data(),
            {html, io_lib:format("~p", [Data])}.        
    </erl>    

    <erl>
        out(Arg) -> 
        Data = utilities:get_raw_data(),
        lists:foreach(fun(X) -> {Id, Fname, Lname} = X, io:format("ID: ~p ", [Lname]) end, Data).
    </erl>

</body>  
</html>
```

The first part of the code runs correctly producing output such as

```
[{3,"Matt","Williamson3"}, {2,"Matt","Williamson2"}, {1,"Matt","Williamson"}]
```

There is no error on the second part, but the web page remains blank. I believe the section

```
io:format("ID: ~p ", [Lname])
```

doesn't print out to the browser.

What do I get to change in order for it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead of the `foreach` line: (untested)

```
    {html, lists:map(fun(X) -> {Id, Fname, Lname} = X, io_lib:format("ID: ~p ", [Lname]) end, Data)}.
```

That is, instead of printing using `io:format`, return the data in a `{html, Iodata}` tuple, as in the first `<erl>` block.

Comment: Thank you! That solution works OK.  wanted to vote it up but I dont have the minimum 15 points needed to do the necessary :-)

Comment: By the way this is what I wanted to do:

<table>
    
    <erl>
        out(Arg) -> 
        Data = utilities:get_raw_data(),
        
        {html, 
            lists:map(
                fun(X) -> 
                    {Id, Fname, Lname} = X, 
                    io_lib:format("~s", ["<tr><td>" ++ Lname ++ "</td><td>" ++ Fname ++ "</td></tr>"]) 
                end,
            Data)
        }.
         
    </erl>
    
</table>

Comment: Good to hear it works! You can "accept" the answer even if you have less than 15 reputation points.